# How to calculate depreciation and tax burden

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property, depreciation

I am having some issues figuring out to calculate how depreciation affects my tax for a rental property. I have an example below.  Is it correctly calculated correctly?

Example:

- Purchase price: `$1,500,000`
- Rehab: `$100,000`
- Land Value: `$750,000`
- Year 1 interest paid: `$41,632`
- Year 1 principal paid: `$23,029`
- Yearly property tax: `$18,750`
- Annual expenses: `$6,200` (Insurance,
  utilities, gardener, and so on)
- Tax rate: `25%`
- The annual rent income is `$129,600`

The house value is `$750,000` (purchase price - land value) + `$100,000` in rehab (all just calculated as 27.5 to make it easier), depreciated over 27.5 years is `$30,909` a year.

If we calculate our year's profit
`$129,600 (rent income) + $23,029 (principal) - $6,200 (annual expenses) - $18,750 (property tax) -  $41,632 (interest paid) = $86,047`

My depreciation is `$30,909` a year, I can subtract that from my taxable income.
`$86,047 - $30,909 = $55,138`
I am then taxed on the `$55,138` at 25% making this year's tax `$13,784.5`
That would mean my annual profit is `$86,047 - $13,784.5 = $72,262.5` and cash flow `$72,262.5 - $23,029 = $49,233.5`

**Is this correct so far?**

Let's say that I hold the property for 10 years and sell it for `$1,950,000`., meaning that I increase the value of the property by `$450,000`. And the land value was `50%` meaning that the building has increased the value by `$225,000`.

**How do I calculate how the depreciation recapture is taken at this sale?**